# SOAP Fault - "Error build soap request" on large request size

Tags: php, web-services, soap, soap-client

This error occurs `SoapFault - Error build soap request` on the requests done by a `PHP` programme which are larger than `100MB`

The stack trace points the error to the line below which is from the client library provided with the service by the vendor:

`$this->__soapCall('ProcessBatch', array($parameters));`

I have changed the service config file as advised by the vendor but they say that this error is happening in PHP side rather than the service.

I have all my `PHP ini` settings changed to accommodate larger POST requests, processing times, file uploads and all that. I can't find a setting about `SOAP` request message length anywhere.

Any help would be highly appreciated!!

Comment: As a representative of the vendor in question I'd like to add that the PHP proxies have been generated by a general purpose tool and are not maintained by us. Everything works fine on requests that are 50MB in size so it appears there is a limitation somewhere in PHP or the wsdl2php generator when it comes to very large requests. The tool in question is https://github.com/walle/wsdl2phpgenerator, it may be worth asking for them to chime in or try to use the latest version of their tool to regenerate the proxies (Looking at github, it hasn't been updated in 3 years). Or use a different wsdl2php